# SQL Server registry error

Tags: sql-server, registry

I installed SQL Server configuration manager and management studio version 2005, on windows 7 Ultimate.

I added a game server to the database and everything worked fine till where I started configuring the game's database and I was prompted to restart/stop/start the server, this is where I was baffled by the errors. I know there are several ways you can do this restart, but I cannot seem to get any to work for issues unknown to me.

I have tried running cmd prompt using the commands:

```
 net stop mssql server
```

also tried manually doing it from management studio, where the option to restart in the pull down menu appears to be unavailable.

It's helpful if I could get rid of this problem before I can move on to extensive table editing as this itself is being a major pain.

Comment: Is there an error message regarding the registry?

Comment: Is that it showing any error message number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the start menu, run: `services.msc`

Scroll down to Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS)

- Replace "SQLEXPRESS" with your instance name

Right click --> Restart